# Express app POST response to HTML page

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, express

I'm currently working on IoT project where I'm trying to POST temperature reading from DHT11 temp. sensor to a node server on my local machine. The POST from the Arduino is just fine and its hitting my server correctly, and on my server.js I get the sensor reading as well. But, how do I print this sensor reading to my HTML page? I use Jade template.

Here is my POST code in server.js

```
app.post('/temp', function(req, res){
    var sensorReading = req.body.sensorInput;
    console.log("Temp: "+sensorReading); // this prints the input correctly to console.
    res.render('index', {temp:sensorReading}); // but this does nothing
});
```

And in the Jade template I have

```
extends layout

block content
   h2 #{pageTitle}

   div
      h1 #{temp}
```

Can someone help me to figure this out?

Comment: Have you imported `body-parser` in your app?

Comment: @Maverick: Yes body-parser is imported and as mentioned in the console.log I get the sensor reading correctly. All I need is to display that reading to the HTML page for the end user. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to set up a web socket connection from your browser page(s) to your server, or have them poll the server to get the most recent response. That code is simply going to render your page back to your Arduino, not your web browser. Also, you will have to find a permanent storage location for your sensor reading as that location is a scope variable that will disappear after the POST.

Comment: really? need a socket io? The poll (temp reading) is done from the Arduino on timed intervals if thats what you mean. My requirement is to get the sensor reading and put it to a cloud instance like Heroku.

Comment: dude, if you want help from people, don't treat them badly, ok, you obviously know nothing at all about Node, good luck!

Comment: I'm sorry if my language hurt your feelings. I never meant to treat you or anyone badly. Of course I know nothing about node or arduino my friend. I have very basic knowledge about node from online free courses. Thank you for helping me. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for your help. I fixed my code as per your suggestion, using socketio and mongodb. Thanks a ton! Cheers!